# fitting step function with variation in the step location with scipy optimize curve_fit

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I am trying to fit x y data which look something like

```
x = np.linspace(-2, 2, 1000)
a = 0.5
yl = np.ones_like(x[x < a]) * -0.4 + np.random.normal(0, 0.05, x[x < a].shape[0])
yr = np.ones_like(x[x >= a]) * 0.4 + np.random.normal(0, 0.05, x[x >= a].shape[0])
y = np.concatenate((yl, yr))
plt.scatter(x, y, s=2, color='k')
```

[image: data]

I'm using a variation of the Heaviside step function

```
def f(x, a, b): return 0.5 * b * (np.sign(x - a))
```

and fitting with

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(f, x, y, p0=p)
```

where p is some initial guess.
for any p curve_fit fit only b and not a
for example:

`popt, pcov = curve_fit(f, x, y, p0=[-1.0, 0])`
we get that popt is [-1., 0.20117665]

`popt, pcov = curve_fit(f, x, y, p0=[.5, 2])`
we get taht popt is [.5, 0.79902]

`popt, pcov = curve_fit(f, x, y, p0=[1.5, -2])`
we get taht popt is [1.5, 0.40128229]

why curve_fit not fitting a?

Comment: Gradient based minimizers are not good at minimizing discontinous functions. You can either try differential evolution as James Phillips points out or replace the model by a continous function with step-like properties, e.g. a Fermi function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by others, `curve_fit` (and all the other solvers in `scipy.optimize`) work well for optimizing continuous but not discrete variables.  They all work by making small (like, at the 1.e-7 level) changes to the parameter values and seeing what (if any) change that makes in the result, and using that change to refine those values until the smallest residual is found.   With your model function using `np.sign`:

```
def f(x, a, b): return 0.5 * b * (np.sign(x - a))
```

such a small change in the value of `a` will not change the model or fit result at all.   That is, first the fit will try the starting value of, say, `a=-1.0` or `a=0.5`, and then will try `a=-0.999999995` or `a=0.500000005`.   Those will both give the same result for `np.sign(x-a)`. The fit does not know that it would need to change `a` by 1 to have any effect on the result. It cannot know this. `np.sign()` and `np.sin()` differ by one letter, but behave very differently in this respect.

It is pretty common for real data to take a step but to be sampled finely enough so that the step does not happen completely in one step.  In that case, you would be able to model the step with a variety of functional forms (linear ramp, error function, arc-tangent, logistic, etc).  The thorough answer from @JamesPhilipps gives one approach.  I would probably use `lmfit` (being one of its main authors) and be willing to guess starting values for the parameters from looking at the data, perhaps:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-2, 2, 1000)
a = 0.5
yl = np.ones_like(x[x < a]) * -0.4 + np.random.normal(0, 0.05, x[x < a].shape[0])
yr = np.ones_like(x[x >= a]) * 0.4 + np.random.normal(0, 0.05, x[x >= a].shape[0])
y = np.concatenate((yl, yr))

from lmfit.models import StepModel, ConstantModel

model = StepModel() + ConstantModel()
params = model.make_params(center=0, sigma=1, amplitude=1., c=-0.5)

result = model.fit(y, params, x=x)

print(result.fit_report())

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(x, y, label='data')
plt.plot(x, result.best_fit, marker='o', color='r', label='fit')
plt.show()
```

which would give a good fit and print out results of

```
[[Model]]
    (Model(step, form='linear') + Model(constant))
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # fitting method   = leastsq
    # function evals   = 50
    # data points      = 1000
    # variables        = 4
    chi-square         = 2.32729556
    reduced chi-square = 0.00233664
    Akaike info crit   = -6055.04839
    Bayesian info crit = -6035.41737
##  Warning: uncertainties could not be estimated:
[[Variables]]
    amplitude:  0.80013762 (init = 1)
    center:     0.50083312 (init = 0)
    sigma:      4.6009e-04 (init = 1)
    c:         -0.40006255 (init = -0.5)
```

Note that it will find the `center` of the step because it assumed there was some finite width (`sigma`) to the step, but then found that width to be smaller than the step size in `x`.  But also note that it cannot calculate the uncertainties in the parameters because, as above, a small change in `center` (your `a`)  near the solution does not change the resulting fit. FWIW the `StepModel` can use a linear, error-function, arc-tangent, or logistic as the step function.

If you had constructed the test data to have a small width to the step, say with
something like

```
from scipy.special import erf    
y = 0.638  * erf((x-0.574)/0.005)  + np.random.normal(0, 0.05, len(x))
```

then the fit would have been able to find the best solution and evaluate the uncertainties.

I hope that explains why the fit with your model function could not refine the value of `a`, and what might be done about it.

Comment: Can this  approach be used to detect the indices of a multi-step function?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a graphical Python fitter using your data and function, with scipy's differential_evolution genetic algorithm module used to provide the initial parameter estimates for curve_fit. That module uses the Latin Hypercube algorithm to ensure a thorough search of parameter space, which requires bounds within which to search. In this example, those bounds are taken from the data max and min values.

[image: plot]

```
import numpy, scipy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution
import warnings


# generate data for testing
x = numpy.linspace(-2, 2, 1000)
a = 0.5
yl = numpy.ones_like(x[x < a]) * -0.4 + numpy.random.normal(0, 0.05, x[x < a].shape[0])
yr = numpy.ones_like(x[x >= a]) * 0.4 + numpy.random.normal(0, 0.05, x[x >= a].shape[0])
y = numpy.concatenate((yl, yr))

# alias data to match pervious example
xData = x
yData = y


def func(x, a, b): # variation of the Heaviside step function
    return 0.5 * b * (numpy.sign(x - a))


# function for genetic algorithm to minimize (sum of squared error)
def sumOfSquaredError(parameterTuple):
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") # do not print warnings by genetic algorithm
    val = func(xData, *parameterTuple)
    return numpy.sum((yData - val) ** 2.0)


def generate_Initial_Parameters():
    # min and max used for bounds
    maxX = max(xData)
    minX = min(xData)

    parameterBounds = []
    parameterBounds.append([minX, maxX]) # search bounds for a
    parameterBounds.append([minX, maxX]) # search bounds for b

    # "seed" the numpy random number generator for repeatable results
    result = differential_evolution(sumOfSquaredError, parameterBounds, seed=3)
    return result.x

# by default, differential_evolution completes by calling curve_fit() using parameter bounds
geneticParameters = generate_Initial_Parameters()

# now call curve_fit without passing bounds from the genetic algorithm,
# just in case the best fit parameters are aoutside those bounds
fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(func, xData, yData, geneticParameters)
print('Fitted parameters:', fittedParameters)
print()

modelPredictions = func(xData, *fittedParameters) 

absError = modelPredictions - yData

SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(yData))

print()
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)

print()


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(xData, yData,  'D')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(xData), max(xData))
    yModel = func(xModel, *fittedParameters)

    # now the model as a line plot
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```

Comment: hi thanks for the thorough replay, but although it is a way for handling the problem it dose not answer my question which is why curve_fit do  not optimize the a parameter.

Comment: We are both fitting the same data and function with curve_fit(), though your code does not fit parameter "a" and my code does. The only difference is in the initial parameter estimates passed to curve_fit(), and my code shows how I determine those working estimates. If this does not answer the question, my suggestion is to downvote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could say that a heavyside can be approximated by a sigmoïd function:

[image: H(x) = 1 / (1 + exp(-2kx)]

or in your case

[image: b / (1 + exp(-2 * k * (x - a))) - b / 2]

You add a parameter `k`, but hopefully it will be big enough in the end, and you get rid of it to find the two other parameters.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x = np.linspace(-2, 2, 1000)
a = 0.5
yl = np.ones_like(x[x < a]) * -0.4 + np.random.normal(0, 0.05, x[x < a].shape[0])
yr = np.ones_like(x[x >= a]) * 0.4 + np.random.normal(0, 0.05, x[x >= a].shape[0])
y = np.concatenate((yl, yr))
plt.scatter(x, y, s=2, color='k')

# def f(x, a, b): return 0.5 * b * (np.sign(x - a))
def g(x, a, b, k): return b / (1 + np.exp(-2 * k * (x - a))) - b / 2
y_sigmoid = g(x, a, 0.8, 10)
plt.scatter(x, y_sigmoid, s=2, color='g')

popt, pcov = curve_fit(g, x, y, p0=[-1.0, 0, 1])
# popt, pcov = curve_fit(f, x, y, p0=[-1.0, 0])
print(popt)
plt.scatter(x, g(x, *popt), s=2, color='r')
```

which gives, as expected:
[**5.02081214e-01** **8.03257583e-01** 3.33970547e+03]

(green: random soft sigmoid, red: curve_fit result)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For more complex and noisy data you can use the error function to fit:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.special import erf
np.random.seed(0)

def func(x,x0,y0,h,a,b=0,c=0):
    return y0 + h/2*erf((x-x0)*a) + b*x + c*x**2

x = np.linspace(0,1,200)
y = (x>0.5)*0.2 + 0.1 + np.random.rand(len(x))*0.2 + x*0.3

popt,pocv = curve_fit(func,x,y,p0 = (np.nanmean(x),np.min(y),np.max(y)-np.min(y),1.0,1.0))

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.plot(x,func(x,*popt))
```

[image]